# Using info from a database as variable values

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am working on a java project and I need to pull some values out of a database and turn them into variables the program will then use to make a billing statement.  I can get the program to connect to the database just fine, and the mySQL statement to call the data I need is easy enough.  I just can't seem to figure out how to then have it put each field returned in the resultset into a separate variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shamelessly lifted from the jdbc tutorial

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                                         ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    ResultSet srs = stmt.executeQuery(
        "SELECT COF_NAME, PRICE FROM COFFEES");
    while (srs.next()) {
            String name = srs.getString("COF_NAME");
            float price = srs.getFloat("PRICE");
            System.out.println(name + "     " + price);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

[You should review the JDBC tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html), and [this section](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) answers your question.